# Instantiating classes - objective c - correct code architecture

Tags: objective-c, class, architecture

Apologies for asking a very simple question but I am writing my first app in objective c and I got slightly confused.

I have created custom class Product:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFU00.png)

Product.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject

@property double price;
@property int amountInt;


//this method will be used for calculating total for each product
- (double) multiplyAmount: (int) amountInt byPrice: (double) price;

@end
```

Product.m

```
#import "Product.h"

@implementation Product

- (double) multiplyAmount: (int) amountInt byPrice: (double) price{
    double amount = (double)amountInt;
    double productPrice = amount * price;
    return productPrice;
}

@end
```

And I have custom view controller (InitialStoreViewController.h)that have properties that I need to use in instance of Product class. So my idea was to instantiate Product class within InitialStoreViewController.m but for some reason Product class is not being recognised there in spite me adding #import "Product.h" at the top:

```
  #import "InitialStoreViewController.h"
    #import "Product.h"
    @implementation InitialStoreViewController



    - (IBAction)peasStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
        peasAmountInt = (int) sender.value;
        NSLog(@"Peas Amount: %i", peasAmountInt);
        peasLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", peasAmountInt];
    }

    - (IBAction)eggsStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
        eggsAmountInt = (int) sender.value;
        NSLog(@"Eggs Amount: %i", eggsAmountInt);
        eggsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", eggsAmountInt];
    }

    - (IBAction)milkStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
        milkAmountInt = (int) sender.value;
        NSLog(@"Milk Amount: %i", milkAmountInt);
        milkLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", milkAmountInt];
    }

    - (IBAction)beansStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
        beansAmountInt = (int) sender.value;
        NSLog(@"Beans Amount: %i", beansAmountInt);
        beansLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", beansAmountInt];
    }

//below is erroring:
    Product *peas = [[Product alloc]init];
    peas.amountInt = 5;
    double peasTotal = [peas multiplyAmount: peas.amountInt byPrice:0.95];
    NSLog(@"Total amount for peas: %f", peasTotal);

    @end
```

Where can/should I instantiate Product class?

Comment: Sounds reasonable from the info. How is it not recognised? What's the error?

Comment: error that I am getting: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant. I have added also more code above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code you've added is outside of any method. You need to move it, probably into the view did load method on the view controller. You should also add a property to the view controller to store the instance of your product so you can update it following each change.

Comment: O dear. I think my view did load its not a part of initial view controller. It's in second view controller. That can't be right can it?

Comment: Every view controller has a view did load method (that you can override)